# Backbonejs HTTP body on put request different on second model save

Tags: backbone.js

My question is related to the second save of a Backbone model and why my HTTP request body is different on the second save.

This is an existing model so a `put` request is sent to the server on both accounts.

The first time I make a change to the model a put request with the following HTTP body is sent to the server:

```
{ id: '12345',
  book_title: 'new title' }
```

If I make another change to the model and save again the following HTTP body is sent:

```
{ id: '12345',
  book_title: 'second title',
  command: 'UPDATE',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false }
```

Why is the extra data added to the HTTP body on the second save?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel really stupid. After looking at the `model.toJSON()` like ezpura suggested I realized that the extra attributes are set right after my `save`.

I then realized that the new attributes was my DB response after saving that I was returning from my server.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone sends all the attributes of model in HTTP body. I doubt you might have set some values to model after your first fetch.

Try consoling

```
  model.toJSON();
```

before your save. it must have  all the values that are seen in your http body.